# Firebase deploy error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/interopRequireDefault'

Tags: javascript, firebase, material-ui, babeljs

I'm trying to deploy firebase functions and I'm having really hard time with multiple problems.

When I try to deploy the app to the firebase I'm getting babel error like:

```
i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (56.91 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting: preparing dev directory for upload...
✔  hosting: 4 files uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating function main...
⚠  functions[main]: Deployment error.
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/interopRequireDefault'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore.js:3:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
```

When I navigate into `@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/interopRequireDefault`, the file present inside `functions` folder.

I'm using `material-ui` along with reactjs.

And the error only shows when I try to use `material-ui` as it states in the error log.

**package.json** inside functions:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.3.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**package.json** in the root of project folder:

```
{
  "name": "Cards",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "babel": "babel src -d functions/src && babel index.js -d functions"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.3.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.0",
    "firebase": "^5.2.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.1.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.19.1",
    "webpack": "^4.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

When I finish writing the code, I run `npm run babel` to convert the code and place that into the functions folder. Then I run `firebase deploy`.

So, what is causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

Also having issues deploying, but managed to solve this one by installing

```
@babel/runtime
```

as a devDependency in the functions folder.